# Why model.predict computes different values in this sample?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

**Context**

Given the following sample, I'm using Jupyter Notebook :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

import numpy as np
x_input = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]])
y_input = np.array([[10]])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation="tanh", input_dim=x_input.shape[1], kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='random_normal'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_input, y_input, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

When I run `model.predict(x_input)` I got:

> array([[9.993563]], dtype=float32)

When I run `model.predict(np.array([[1,2,5,4,5]]))` I got:

> array([[10.180285]], dtype=float32)

**Question**

Should I get the very same prediction in both cases? (While using the same fit model)

Comment: are you aware of the number 5 in the middle of `np.array([[1,2,5,4,5]])`?

Comment: Thx, see my comment on the answer. Unfortunately I can not delete this sad question, answer exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the inputs are no the same, the first is `[1,2,3,4,5]` and the second is `[1,2,5,4,5]`. The third element of both arrays are not the same.

Comment: My bad, I reviewed zillion times still... I do not know I leave this sad thing here or delete...